# Sliding Menu+Actionbar Sherlock - VFY:Unable to resolve static field crash

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, dalvik, slidingmenu

I have been working on the android swipe menu library and seem to have installed in correctly along side the actions bar sherlock library. I tried to open a demo example but keep on getting the same error, In fact, Any project using based on `sliding menu+action` sherlock generates the same error in the console and the app crashes.

I have tried various fixes including things like having only one .jar file in only the action bar sherlock library or, trying to make sure that the .jar is actually present inside and not just in the build path, but afraid i ran out of luck. I have attached a picture of the error I keep on getting along with my eclipse IDE.

Please feel free to ask me for more info, I have been stuck for a day but can not find my resources for this error.

```
http://postimage.org/image/wwcz1q2pl/

<a href='http://postimage.org/image/wwcz1q2pl/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s4.postimage.org/wwcz1q2pl/problem.jpg' border='0' alt="problem" /></a>
```

Comment: The library and library 1 are the library projects for the action sherlock and sliding menu and they are present inside my work space.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you pasted the logcat output (starting from the "unable to resolve" line and continuing through the exception) into your question, rather than including a URL for a screen shot of the same.  For some reason the VM can't find `com.slidingmenu.lib.R$layout`.